# How to find display name of user who has created maximum no.of posts?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

My 2 tables:

Posts.csv-

```
id
post_type
creationdate
score
viewcount
owneruserid
title
answercount
commentcount
```

Users.csv-

```
id
reputation
displayname
loc
age
```

I know some logic that i need to group owneruserid and then take count of id under Posts.csv.

Then link it with User.csv i.e. join it by owneruserid from post.csv and id from users.csv.

Please provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have listed the logic, build on those steps.See the below script.Load data,join on owneruserid,id then group by the owneruserid.Foreach group generate the count of the posts.Order the final result by descending order and get the top most row.

```
A = LOAD 'Posts.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (int id,chararray:post_type,chararray:creationdate,int:score,int:viewcount,int:owneruserid,chararray:title,int:answercount,int:commentcount);
B = LOAD 'Users.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (int:id,int:reputation,chararray:displayname,chararray:loc,int:age);
C = JOIN A BY (owneruserid), B BY (id);
D = GROUP C BY A.owneruserid;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group as userid,B.displayname,COUNT(A.id) as TotalPosts;
F = ORDER E BY TotalPosts DESC;
G = LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: grunt> E = FOREACH D GENERATE group as userid,B.displayname,COUNT(id) as TotalPosts;

2016-06-04 09:03:18,020 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: 
<line 6, column 59> Invalid field projection. Projected field [id] does not exist in schema: group:int,C:bag{:tuple(A::id:int,A::post_type:int,A::creationdate:chararray,A::score:int,A::viewcount:int,A::owneruser_id:int,A::title:chararray,A::answercount:chararray,A::commentcount:chararray,B::id:int,B::reputation:int,B::displayname:chararray,B::loc:chararray,B::age:int)}.

Comment: I've edited the post.Just use the relation A to project the field id.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, ['Post.csv', 'post.csv']), ignore_index=True)
df
df1.loc[0:4,"id":"viewcount"]
df.loc[: , "reputation"]